# Building a Causal Impact model and Understanding the results

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, causalimpact

I work for a company that helps online retailers to group their inventory into google ad campaigns. I am using [Causal Impact](https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html#faq) to determine whether the release of a new feature within our software had an impact on the total impressions that an online retailer received through google ads - an impression is counted each time the retailers ad is shown on a google search result page.

**Approach**

To begin with, I just have one X variable.

**y** - impressions over the past 365 days.

**X** - daily searches for the term ‘garden furniture’ using google trends

I expected searches for 'garden furniture' to have a good correlation with the impressions of this particular retailer (correlation was +0.58). Importantly, google search terms won't be influenced by the change we made to our software and therefore satisfies the key requirement that the X variables are not affected by the intervention.

After standardising, the data looks like this.

[image: Impressions against garden_furniture]

And running Causal Impact shows that the intervention did not quite have a significant effect (p=0.07).

```
pre_period_start = '20220405'
per_period_end = '20230207'
post_period_start = '20230208'
post_period_end = '20230329'


pre_period = [pre_period_start, per_period_end]
post_period = [post_period_start, post_period_end]    
ci = CausalImpact(dated_data, pre_period, post_period)
ci.plot()
```

[image]

[image]

**Questions**

1. How can I verify that my X variables are doing a good job of predicting y?

From this [notebook](https://github.com/WillianFuks/tfcausalimpact/blob/master/notebooks/getting_started.ipynb), in section 2.5: Understanding results, it suggests the below code gives the values for beta.X. The value here 0.06836722 seems quite low and suggests that the garden_furniture searches don't explain impressions very well. Is this the correct interpretation?

```
 tf.reduce_mean(ci.model.components_by_name['SparseLinearRegression/'].params_to_weights(
   ci.model_samples['SparseLinearRegression/_global_scale_variance'],
   ci.model_samples['SparseLinearRegression/_global_scale_noncentered'],
   ci.model_samples['SparseLinearRegression/_local_scale_variances'],
   ci.model_samples['SparseLinearRegression/_local_scales_noncentered'],
   ci.model_samples['SparseLinearRegression/_weights_noncentered'],
), axis=0)
```

<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.06836722], dtype=float32)>

2. When adding another X variable to the model, how can I determine whether adding that variable was useful or not?
3. I’ve also attempted to backtest the model by selecting the first 90 data points and an imaginary intervention date. As shown below, we do not get a significant effect. However, I’m concerned that the predictions don’t seem to align that closely with the actual y. Does this look like a problem?

[image]

4. General advice - Any suggestions on improving the analysis would be greatly appreciated as this is the first time I’ve used Causal Impact. In particular, I'm struggling on

- selecting additional X variables to use
- whether changing the data frequency to weekly would help with predictions